# What arguments does "sequences" paramater take in theano.scan and how are they interpreted

Tags: python-2.7, theano, theano.scan

I have taken the following code from http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/scan.html

```
    import numpy

    coefficients = theano.tensor.vector("coefficients")
    x = T.scalar("x")

    max_coefficients_supported = 10000

    # Generate the components of the polynomial
    components, updates = theano.scan(fn=lambda coefficient, power, free_variable: coefficient * (free_variable ** power),
                              outputs_info=None,
                              sequences=[coefficients, theano.tensor.arange(max_coefficients_supported)],
                              non_sequences=x)
```

The code here was meant to explain "sequences" parameter.
Here is my question:

1. How are the sequences fed? The first term "coefficients" is a tensor variable. The second term "theano.tensor.arange(max_coefficients)" is a tensor variable which on using eval() gives a list with [0......999]. The tutorial says-

   ```
   "The tensor(s) to be looped over should be provided to scan using the sequence keyword argument."
   ```

   How is the looping happening here based on the arguments provided here in "sequences"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the arguments is : sequence[t],outputs_infor,non_sequence

```
 coefficients[t]
 theano.tensor.arange(max_coefficients_supported)[t]
 x
```

outputs_infor saves the result of the previous iteration